# How to save a Progress Dialog state correctly?

Tags: android

In my app when i do some long work i'm using a Progress Dialog while the work isn't finished.
I'm looking for it in every place but without sucess. Everything that i founded is all about saving user interface elements states.

Then, i would like to know how i can save progress dialog state correctly ?

I want this working because when the orientation screen change the app crashes.

Shoul i use onSaveInstanceState() method ? How ? I try using saving as a bundle but without succes...

Any advice would be nice...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to handle the screen orientation you must use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

you can find a more extensive explanation about screen orientation here: [Faster Screen Orientation.](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html)

Comment: Thanks ! I read about onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and there says : onRetainNonConfigurationChange() should be used only to retain data that is expensive to load. Then, is it really good to use ? Or the below answer is more appropriated ?

Comment: well, it depends what your activity do, you say that your activity performs a long work, so, i suppose that you download many data or something, then in that case i would use onRetainNonConfigurationChanged... but in other cases (depending of use case) i would use onConfigurationChanged()...

Comment: thanks for the explanation.. i'll go to make more tests and after that i put what i decided ... thanks anyway !

Comment: I get 404 when clicking your link.

Comment: Maybe they have changed the link, but you will find it here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Answer (score 1):

I think, your dialog crashes on orientation change because you are not using

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int dialogID, Bundle args)
```

and

```
showDialog(dialogID);
```

to show your dialog.
I had the same problem with an alert dialog. As I see it, if you don't create dialog that way, it becomes linked to your activity, and when activity is dead, the system finds that a dialog still try to access that dead activity, not new one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to the manifest file for the activity in which you are showing the dialog:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this in my applications is overriding the onConfigurationChanged() method in the Activity like so:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
        //Just switch the layout without respawning the activity
        super.onConfigurationChanged(config);   
    }
```

This hasn't given me any issues as of yet and my Activity doesn't reload or restart when the orientation is changed.

Comment: Thanks ! I made some tests here and its nice too =)